# Arg able to be two different types, discord.Member and str

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

How would I make a command able to have two different possibilities of an arg?  For example: `?settings staff-role <@role | role name | Default | None>`.
My current code is:

```
@commands.guild_only()
@settings.command(aliases=["staff-role"])
async def staffRole(self, ctx, role: discord.Role):
    #if role is "default" set it to default
    #if role is "none" remove all roles
```

Comment: The `Role` [converter](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#converters) should be able to process both inputs into `Role` objects already.  Have you tried sending the role name to the command?  What error do you see that makes you think it isn't working?

Comment: Sorry, I phrased my question incorrectly @PatrickHaugh. I would like to make it possible to accept strings and roles.

Answer (score 0):

In the case you describe, I think the best scenario would be to allow your command to have a default value, so it can be omitted instead of asking the caller to pass `"none"`

```
@commands.guild_only()
@settings.command(aliases=["staff-role"])
async def staffRole(self, ctx, role: discord.Role=None):
    if role:
        # set it to role
    else:
        # role was not provided
```

Comment: I would like the caller to be able to pass "None", how would this be possible?

Comment: @Dextication You would stop using the `discord.Role` converter, and instead use `discord.utils.get(ctx.guild, name=role)` to attempt to resolve the correct role. Your command would accept strings, and it would be your responsibility to find the associated roles.